# How to use hostname in my j2 template? I've met some errors while trying

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I've tried to use j2 template for ssl key generation. But I met an issue that my conf file can load ansible hostname.

All my servers are Centos7

my j2:

```
{% set count=2 %}
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha512
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C = CN
ST = GZ
L = SZ
O = TR_Cloud
OU = dev
CN = {{ ansible_hostname }}

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
{% for host in groups['etcd'] %}
DNS.{{ count }} = {{ host }}
{% set count=count+1 %}
{% endfor %}
{% set count=2 %}
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
{% for host in groups['etcd'] %}
DNS.{{ count }} = {{ host['ansible_hostname'] }}
{% set count=count+1 %}
{% endfor %}

[ v3_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage=keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName=@alt_names
```

ERROR:
'unicode object' has no attribute 'ansible_hostname'

I want to update hostname on the blank.

Comment: You have two loops to get your dns names from group `etcd` and the second is wrong. `host['ansible_hostname']` does not exist. Keep the first loop only.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've found the issue now, thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zeitounator said. There is a error in host['ansible_hostname']. I've modified my code so as to copied well with other situations.

```
{% set count=2 %}
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha512
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C = CN
ST = GZ
L = SZ
O = TR_Cloud
OU = dev
CN = {{ inventory_hostname }}

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
{% for host in groups['etcd'] %}
DNS.{{ count }} = {{ host }}
{% set count=count+1 %}
{% endfor %}
{% set count=2 %}
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
{% for host in groups['etcd'] %}
IP.{{ count }} = {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_'+interface]['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% set count=count+1 %}
{% endfor %}

[ v3_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage=keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName=@alt_names
```